# How do MongoDB cursors work when used with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Node.js with the npm package `mongodb`. When I use `findOne(...)`, I get a result which is directly the item I searched for. When I use `find(...)` instead, I don't get an array of elements, I get a cursor which looks very weird if you `console.log` it.

My question is why does it return a cursor instead of the array of elements and is the `cursor.forEach(...)` call then asynchronous or how can the client get data out of the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a cursor instead of an array to provide flexibility to the client to access the results in whatever way is optimal for its needs.

To get an array of all results, you can call the async [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) method on the cursor:

```
collection.find({...}).toArray((err, docs) => {...});
```

Same thing for `aggregate`:

```
collection.aggregate([{$match: {...}}]).toArray((err, docs) => {...});
```

Comment: and the normal `cursor.forEach(...)` code is doing the same but giving results one by one, right? And it is asynchronous too, so I have to basically "wait two times" for a response from the server?

Comment: Yes, `forEach` is also async and provides the documents one at a time. But `find` synchronously returns the cursor, so you don't have to wait for that.

Comment: there is no such thing for aggregate. There it returns a cursor and I have to wait 2 times. Isn't this a performance overhead when I know that there is only one result? Can't I tell in the request that I just want  the data and don't need a cursor?

Comment: Actually, it's the same for `aggregate`. See updated answer.

Comment: Ahhh I just understood what you actually meant. I thought what you did would be 1 waiting and after that `.toArray` and again waiting. But you do all this within the first request so that you only wait one time. Thanks a lot  Johnny :)